# How to check a weston environment

Tags: c, gtk3, wayland

How can I, at runtime check whether the program is running in a Weston environment.
I program a Gtk+-3.0 in C and I want depending on the Display Server technology the GUI is running different windows size and similar hints.

To be more precise. My system is a very small embedded linux. I start weston via systemd:

```
# weston systemd service unit file                                                                          

[Unit]
Description=Weston launcher
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Environment=HOME=/root
ExecStart=/root/weston.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
Alias=display-manager.service
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

This is the startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Weston startup file.
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/shm/wayland"
mkdir -p "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
chmod 0700 "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"

/usr/bin/weston --tty=1 --log=/var/log/weston.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/weston.1.html

Try getting this environment variable -

**WAYLAND_DISPLAY**

example, using getenv() ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
   printf("WESTON : %s\n", getenv("WAYLAND_DISPLAY"));
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately WAYLAND_DISPLAY is not set in my environment. I start weston via systemd and a custom bash script. This is a very small embedded project.
`#!/bin/bash;
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/shm/wayland";
/usr/bin/weston --tty=1 --log=/var/log/weston.log`